# Compare strings with specialized charcters

Tags: text-processing, awk, data

If I have a lookup table

```
cat  tmp1
[//rtwttwtr*fgg]\\\erw``~ 1
^774574574565665f[[[//]\] 2
()42543^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D353535345****@3242- 3
```

and a number of strings to be looked up from the first column of the lookup table, and see if the compared strings contain each or the other completely (one string is substring of the other) , then retun the second column  looked up value.

So if my second file is

```
cat  tmp2
[//rtwtt
[//rtwttwtr*fgg]\\\erw``~
[//rtwttwtr*fgg]\\\erw``~4353535^^^7
()42543^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D353535345****@3242--
rwerq5555525525
```

then my desired output is

```
[//rtwtt 1
[//rtwttwtr*fgg]\\\erw``~ 1 
[//rtwttwtr*fgg]\\\erw``~4353535^^^7 1
()42543^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D353535345****@3242-- 3
rwerq5555525525
```

The lookup criteria is either the lookup table string or the query string is a substring of the other for the match to be true.

Here is what I tried,

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next} { for(as in a) { if(($1~as) || (as~$1)) print $1,a[as]; continue}}' tmp1 tmp2
```

But i`m getting invalid range error

Comment: Your input strings (first column) look like regular expressions to AWK, thus the error. You'll have to process them to escape the special symbols like slashes, square brackets and the like. What AWK implementation are you using? Do you need for a solution to be portable across different implementations?

Comment: Here is the info : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7, GNU Awk 3.1.7 . I need to run this on this machine only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this awk, it doesn't print the field(rwerq5555525525) from tmp2 file that doesn't match.
Perhaps some of the experts can help with that detail.

```
FNR==NR {
    a[$1]=$2;
    next;
}
{
    s1=split($1,B,"")
    lineY="";
    for(j=1;j<=s1;j++)
    {
        if (B[j] ~ /[[:alnum:]]/)
        {
            lineY=lineY B[j]
        }
        else
        {
            lineY=lineY "\\"B[j]
        }
    }
    for (item in a)
    {
        s=split(item,C,"");
        linex="";
        for(i=1;i<=s;i++)
        {
            if (C[i] ~ /[[:alnum:]]/)
            {
                linex=linex C[i]
            }
            else
            {
                linex=linex "\\"C[i]
            }
        }
        if ((match(item,lineY)) || (match($1,linex)))
        {
            print $1" "a[item];
        }   
    }   
}
```

$ awk -Pf script.awk temp1.txt temp2.txt

```
[//rtwtt 1
[//rtwttwtr*fgg]\\\erw``~ 1 
[//rtwttwtr*fgg]\\\erw``~4353535^^^7 1
()42543^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D353535345****@3242-- 3
```